# An office worker

Tags: questions

A: So you work for that company. Are you some kind of hotshot business man?

B: Me? No, I'm just an office worker.

Is "office worker" almost only used to refer to people who work in a small cubicle or is it just as commonly used to refer to people who have their own fancy office in a big company?

Is it natural to say "**just** an office worker" in my example?

Answer (score 1):

#### "Office worker" refers to white collar work.

"Office worker" isn't usually used to refer exclusively to someone who works in a cubicle or to someone who works in a private office,  but to someone who works in an office building in general,  which would include both group. Depending upon context, it might or might not exclude higher management, like it probably would in your quote, since it also includes lower-level workers; in other contexts, such as a labor statistics report comparing office workers against service workers, tradesmen, unskilled labor, etc., it probably wouldn't.